# Use Bulk insert to insert deleted records back to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

I have created a job to delete records in database based on some criteria, this works just fine. In fact the job copies the records into a file before deleting them. Meaning that I always have a copy of the deleted data.

However, and in case the deleted data needs to be restored back in database. I need to insert the records back to the same place where they have been deleted. meaning that the insert should not work as if I insert new records. Is that possible? And if yes how to do it?

This is the SQL code to delete the records from the database:

```
delete from table_1 
where Table_1ID IN (select distinct Table_2ID
                    from Table_2 T2
                    left join
                        (select *
                         from Table3) x on T2.Table_2ID = x.Table_2ID 
                    where ((x.Table3ID is null and T2.DateTime < '2018-12-12') 
                           or x.ExpireDate < '2018-12-12')) 

Declare @cmd varchar(1000);

select @cmd = 'bcp "select * from ##DeletedTable_1" queryout '
        + '"D:\Test\Deleted' 
        + convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112)    -- YYYYMMDD
        + replace(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 108), ':', '') -- HHMMSS
        + '.txt" -t, -c -T'


print @cmd
```

when the data is imported to the txt file. It looks like this

```
144132,3,422,113,64,69,System , ,2009-09-22 14:20:05.940,2009-09-22 00:00:00.000,2009-09-22 14:20:05.940,2009-09-23 13:49:50.920,-Louise ,000000001C5677E2
```

so it does not have quotation marks around the strings. And I wonder if this would be an issue?

I have tried to do the following but it did not work.

```
BULK INSERT mydb.table_1
FROM 'D:\Test\Deleted'
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "it did not work". If you have an error, include it. Did it succeed, but no records were inserted? Did nothing happen and you dont know what the status is?

Comment: I get the following error when I try to execute the bulk insert Msg 2809, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The request for procedure 'Table_1' failed because 'Table_1' is a table object.

Comment: is "mydb" a database name or a schema name? If it's a database name, then you are missing mention of a schema between "mydb" and "table_1".

Comment: @jamie, you were right and I had to add the schema name, however that did not fix the issue of inserting the data from the flat file. meaning, I still not able to insert the rows.

Comment: and what is the error now?

Comment: @jamie I get the following:-   Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: @jamie I updated the question with information about the txt file where I bulk insert to the database.

Comment: you need to read up on the "bulk insert" command. It has default/assumed values for the various paramters/options you can specify. I believe the default for field terminator is "tab". But your file is comma-delimeted and you do not specify any options with your "bulk insert" command?